# показать полосу загрузки пользователю

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel

в контроллере производится следующая задача:

- Получаем данные json - первый запрос
- Еще 1 json запрос
- Производим некоторые операции с данными
- Запихиваем все операции в таблицу

На все про все уходит от 1 до 5 секунд. Хотелось бы, чтобы пользователь видел прогресс. Можно ли как то показать пользователю, что именно делает программа в данную секунду? К примеру (Статус: Получаю данные | Обновляю таблицу). И если нет, то можно ли сделать какую-то заглушку на время загрузки? Типа кружок крутится вертится или еще чего. Но в идеале бы знать, что именно происходит.

Comment: если это ajax запрос то кто вам мешает показать картинку с анимацией до получения результата если хотите конкретный код приведите свой и что не получается

Comment: это не ajax запрос, обычная <form action=...

Comment: @PaulWall Вы же отправляете куда-то эту форму и соответственно вы делаете запрос куда-то

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего разделить прогресс бар на куски по 25% (100/4). Перед началом какой-то задачи мы говорим об этом пользователю и показываем процент.

```
function manage_preloader(data) {
    console.log(data.action, data.done + '%');

    // по идее data.done меняет width прогресс бара
    // с data.action понятно
}


function progress() {
    manage_preloader({
        action: 'Выполняю цикл',
        done: 25;
    });
    for () {...};



    manage_preloader({
        action: 'Цикл завершен, отправляю запрос к серверу.',
        done: 50;
    });
    $.ajax(...);



    manage_preloader({
        action: 'Сервер прислал данные, работаю с DOM.',
        done: 75;
    });
    $('div').css(...);



    manage_preloader({
        action: 'Работа с DOM заершена успешно.',
        done: 100;
    });
}
```

В целом логика, я думаю, ясна. Рад, если чем-то помог.

Comment: у меня к сожалению не через ajax это делается((

Comment: Это универсальный вариант. Вызывайте manage_preloader в нужных местах или даже коллбэках.

Comment: у меня 1 ajax форма генерирует множество обычных, и пихать еще ajax очень геморойно(((( я думал может есть проще способ

Answer (score 2):

как вариант сделать через [setinterval](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

а при получении данных использовать redis - туда прогресс пихать - и на setinterval получать процент

Это самый простой способ - если более сложней - то можно через веб сокеты - когда серверная часть посылает данные в клиент через открытый веб сокет

Answer (score 1):

Такое решение написал для вас:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const input = document.querySelector('input')

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  api(input.value)

  preloadStart()
})


const create = ({ avatar_url, id, location }) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  const p = document.createElement('p')
  const img = document.createElement('img')

  img.src = avatar_url

  p.innerText = `ID: ${id} ----------- Location: ${location}`

  p.insertBefore(img, p.firstChild)
  div.append(p)
  document.querySelector('.content').append(div)
}

const api = async (nickname) => {
    preloadStart()
     try {
          const response = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${nickname}`)

          if (response.status === 200) {
            preloadStop()
            create(response.data)
          }
     } catch({ request: {status} }) {
     preloadStop()
        if (status === 404) {
          alert('Не найдено!')
        }
     }
}

const preloadStart = () => {
  const preload = document.querySelector('.preload')
  const content = document.querySelector('.content')

  preload.classList.remove('d-none')
  content.classList.add('d-none')
}

const preloadStop = () => {
  const preload = document.querySelector('.preload')
  const content = document.querySelector('.content')

  setTimeout(() => {
    preload.classList.add('d-none')
    content.classList.remove('d-none')
  }, 3000)
}

api('andre-w2')
```

```css
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    img {
      border-radius: 100%;
      width: 50px;
    }
    .preload {
      display: flex;
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    #icon-preload {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      border-radius: 100%;

      animation: changeColor 2s infinite;
    }
    .d-none {
      display: none;
    }

    @keyframes changeColor {
      0%, 50% {
        background-color: blue;
      }
      100% {
        background-color: red;
      }
    }
```

```html
  <div class="preload">
    <span id="icon-preload"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="d-none content">
    <div>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Никнейм с github">
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.27.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```